# Not finding all items in a MongoDB TypeORM collection

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, typeorm

When using the `find` and `findOne` methods to get data from collection, it's not returning all items in the collection.

**Collection.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Collection {

    @ObjectIdColumn()
    id !: string ;

    @Column()
    symbol !: string 

    @Column()
    name !: string

    @Column()
    description !: string

    @Column()
    image !: string

    @Column()
    totalItems !: number

    @Column()
    website!: string

    @Column ()
    categories!: string[];

    @Column()
    stats!: Stats[];

    @Column()
    isListed!: boolean;

    
}
```

**find.ts**

```
const collection = getMongoRepository(Collection)
await collection.findOne({ where: {  symbol : { $eq : symbol}}})
```

**Result**

```
Collection {
  id: 6285e19cfc929d11a2ec35fd,
  symbol: 'solpunks',
  name: 'SolPunks',
  description: 'SolPunks are one of the very first NFTs on the Solana blockchain. Each of these 10,000 SolPunks has attributes that make them unique according to a defined rarity system.',
  image: 'https://bafkreiaoifjzhau3clwdbtap7mekvdardfg25xl24kbexc7syvws35ifk4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/',
  website: '',
  categories: [ 'pfps' ],
  stats: null 
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
Collection {
  id: 6285e19cfc929d11a2ec35fd,
  symbol: 'solpunks',
  name: 'SolPunks',
  description: 'SolPunks are one of the very first NFTs on the Solana blockchain. Each of these 10,000 SolPunks has attributes that make them unique according to a defined rarity system.',
  image: 'https://bafkreiaoifjzhau3clwdbtap7mekvdardfg25xl24kbexc7syvws35ifk4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/',
  website: '',
  categories: [ 'pfps' ],
  totalItems : 9999,
  isListed : true,
  stats: null 
}
```

**Issue**

`totalItems` and `isListed` are missing

Comment: can you post the sample data which is in collection?

Comment: @varman updated Expected Result

Comment: That cannot be the case. I doubt that you have those two fields in the db as well.

Comment: yes it is in db

Comment: check this https://ibb.co/7jKk8zR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's issue with naming of `totalItems` and `isListed`.after I change that to snake case it worked fine.